# Replacing Domain Controller with a new box, same name/IP?

Tags: windows, domain, vmware-esx, controller

We have a 2003 DC that I want to virtualize as the lease on the hardware is expiring.

It's a DC, GC, FSMO master, DNS, DHCP and TS License Server.

I want/need to keep the same name and IP on the new box, and my plan right now is:

Build the new box and add to the domain with temp name/IP, patch etc. then dcpromo and make it a DC.

Sit back and wait for things to replicate.

Transfer FSMO roles, install DHCP and migrate/configure scopes, authorize new server, de-authorize existing server so now this one is our DHCP server.

De-Activate TS Licensing on current DC.

DCPromo current DC and demote, change name and IP and force replication amongst remaining DC's.

Rename new DC to name of existing DC, reboot, force sync etc.

Change IP of newly renamed DC to required IP, force replication.

Install TS Licensing role and install/activate TS CALs.

Hopefully sit back and admire my new DC with the same name and IP of the old hardware.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: why does it need to have the same name/ip?  is adding an additional IP on the box & using a cname good enough?

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do a P2V using vSphere Converter?

Comment: This works very good in almost all cases, I virtualized our old DC's this way to retain any old legacy setup within our domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to virtualize the box, use [Disk2VHD](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ee656415.aspx)

Oh, and once you've made a server a DC, you cannot rename. (well you can, [but enjoy hell](http://www.petri.co.il/windows_2003_domain_controller_rename.htm))

Comment: We use ESX rather than Hyper-V and I'm not interested in doing any kind of P2V as it's more trouble than it's worth trying to remove all the HP agents and stuff.

Can you expand on "enjoy hell" as I've renamed DC's before with no issue, I just don't do it often hence the sanity check.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757349(WS.10).aspx suggests what I thought, which is that there's little more it than renaming it and replicating.

Comment: I would think that removing agents is less trouble than renaming a DC.

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you running two DC's?

Setup the first Virtual Machine as a new secondary with a different name, promote etc,  decomission the old physical, rebuild the old physical as virtual with the same name, promote.